# CloudFormation template parameter inside bash command substitution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a commadelimted list  and template snippet like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  IPWhitelist:
    Description: Comma-delimited list of CIDR blocks.
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: '1.1.1.1/32, 2.2.2.2/32, 3.3.3.3/32'
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT5M
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Init':
        configSets:
          foobar_setup:
            - configure_foo
        configure_foo:
          commands:
            01_config:
              command: !Sub |
                IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$(echo ${IPWhitelist} | sed -e 's/[][]//g')"
                for IP in "${!array[@]}";do echo $IP >> /foo/bar/allowed_ips.txt;done
```

I'd like to run the following command in the Init type commands key:

```
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$(echo ${IPWhitelist} | sed -e 's/[][]//g')"
for IP in "${array[@]}";do echo $IP >> /etc/squid/allowed_ips.txt;done
```

so for the `array` as the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) says

> To write a dollar sign and curly braces (${}) literally, add an
> exclamation point (!) after the open curly brace, such as ${!Literal}.
> AWS CloudFormation resolves this text as ${Literal}.

What about the first line? how to substitute cloudformation parameter inside bash command substitution $()?

Error message:

```
Template contains errors.: Template error: variable IPWhitelist in
Fn::Sub expression does not resolve to a string
```

Comment: It isn't working because `IPWhitelist` is a `CommaDelimitedList`, not a `String`. You need to convert it to a `String` using `Fn::Join` or just change the parameter type to `String`

Comment: I've already figured it out. Convert it to string and replace command with ```echo ${IPWhitelist} | tr "," "\n" | tee /foor/bar/allowed_ips.txt```. Thanks for help!